# Resize uploaded image to proportion

Tags: php, html, image, upload, resize

I have been creating an image uploading site for a while now but have been stuck on a certain part of it. On the second page, once the upload has been completed, i have displayed the various links you would expect. However. I would like to add a thumbnail to the page, or even a bigger picture, but it needs to be a certain width. I have tried many times to write a little script to take the dimensions and apply some maths to it, but to no avail.

I would really like if someone had a script or an idea how to do the above. Remember all the image sizes uploaded are different and i would want a 50x50 image being blown up to 250x250.

```
<?php
```

```
function imgResize($width, $height, $target) {

     if ($width > $height) {
     $percentage = ($target / $width);
     } else {
     $percentage = ($target / $height);
     }


     $width = round($width * $percentage);
     $height = round($height * $percentage);
     return "width=\"$width\" height=\"$height\"";

     }

     ?>
```

Thanks,
Harry

Comment: "blowing up" an image is very bad practice as it will result in a very low quality image / stretched image.

Comment: What does it return, because your code looks right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple math:

```
$original_width = 50;
$original_height = 50;
$width = 250;
$ratio = $width/$original_width;

$height = $original_height * $ratio;
```